# VideoJS's live UI -- any way to manually manipulate seek behavior?

Tags: javascript, video.js

I would like to both

1) Programmatically navigate the user to a specific point on the seekbar.
2) Prevent the user from clicking anything but a few spots on the seekbar.

As far as I can tell this is totally impossible. Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually move to any spot on the seekbar with Player.currentTime(seconds).

You can have custom behavior for what isn't seekable by listening for the seeked and seeking events, e.g. https://codepen.io/rosswaycaster/pen/gpzLao

```
 myPlayer.on("seeking", function(event) {
      if (currentTime < myPlayer.currentTime()) {
        myPlayer.currentTime(currentTime);
      }
    });

    myPlayer.on("seeked", function(event) {
      if (currentTime < myPlayer.currentTime()) {
        myPlayer.currentTime(currentTime);
      }
    });

    setInterval(function() {
      if (!myPlayer.paused()) {
        currentTime = myPlayer.currentTime();
      }
    }, 1000);
```